# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "paquete chileno"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, colombia

Hace algunas semanas, revisaba videos en Youtube del humorista Gerly Hassan.

En una de sus presentaciones en el programa Sábados Felices del Canal Caracol, hizo referencia a la expresión **paquete chileno** en una parte del chiste que mas o menos decía así:

> *... que ella no me vaya a salir con el **paquete chileno**.*

Se puede *asumir* a qué se refiere con la expresión; pero buscando en internet, no encuentro información sobre el origen de dicha expresión.

Por esto pregunto:

**¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "paquete chileno"?**

Comment: Por [lo que leo](http://www.elpais.com.co/elpais/judicial/noticias/como-estafa-paquete-chileno-enterese-y-evite-caer-ella-este-fin-ano) se trata de una estafa consistente en hacer creer a una persona que se le dará un paquete con mucho dinero. A cambio, esta persona da todo lo que tenga en su poder en ese momento (dinero, joyas). Después se percata de que tal paquete no tenía el dinero que parecía. La noticia que enlazo es de un periódico colombiano, tal vez es allí donde se da esta estafa y tiene el nombre porque lo cometieron chilenos inicialmente.

Comment: @fedorqui, gracias por su aporte, comprendo su significado, pero mi pregunta es sobre el origen de la expresión :).

Comment: Justamente el origen es el que describe @fedorqui. Es una expresión colombiana que se origina en una estafa cometida inicialmente por "chilenos" usando un "paquete" que no contenía la plata que se suponía debía contener.

Comment: @DGaleano, en realidad esperaba mas "historia" / "trasfondo"; sé por la referencia que es una expresión colombiana, pero no dice su historia. Si desean editar al pregunta para redactar mejor la misma, pueden hacerlo :)

Comment: Soy chileno y me he reído mucho leyendo esta pregunta, no conocía la expresión. Pues sí, los chilenos sabemos que somos famosos en otros países por esta triste causa. Qué orgullo...

Comment: En Chile, a este delito se le denomina "cambiazo" o "cuento del tío".

Comment: En Bolivia tambien le llamamos el "cuento del tío".

Comment: El paquete chileno **NO DATA DEL EXILIO POR LA DICTADURA** de Pinocho. Se conoció en Colombia al menos desde los años cincuenta, si no fue antes.

Comment: Soy chilena y me "desayuno" con este dicho popular al parecer venezolano y/o colombiano... Que orgullo! Cueck!

Answer (score 3):

Soy de Venezuela, y también conocemos el término "Paquete Chileno".

El folklore popular indica que el origen ocurre hace varias décadas, durante el éxodo de ciudadanos chilenos que, debido a conflictos políticos, se radicaban en (este caso) Venezuela. Algunos de ellos eligieron dedicarse a estafar a los locales, ofreciéndoles supuestos "paquetes" que contenían un bien valioso (joyas, divisas extranjeras, un cheque al portador, etc.) con el pretexto de tener una urgencia o de verse imposibilitados de usar el contenido. Le ofrecían al local entregarle la misma a cambio de un precio muy inferior, a lo cual el incauto local accedía considerándolo una excelente negociacion. El chileno se iba, y el local trataba de hacer uso del mencionado paquete, encontrando que solo contenía papel periódico o un cheque de goma. Muchas veces el hecho de que el chileno en cuestion fuese de piel blanca y tuviera un acento sureño jugaba un papel clave en el poder de convencimiento, estafa que, en cambio, sería muy difícil de realizar por un local de piel obscura.

Comment: Estás equivocado, esta comunidad no es de informática. Es una comunidad para las personas que están aprendiendo Español así como también los que son nativos ayudan a los aprendices.

Comment: @sujeto1, Bienvenido a Spanish.StackExchange, por favor, [visita el tour](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour) para conocer mas acerca de este sitio. En Stack Exchange, puedes encontrar varios sitios dedicados a diferentes ramas del conocimiento.

Comment: @Rodrigo, no tengo suficientes puntos para responder tu propia respuesta, pero primero que nunca mencione Colombia, sino Venezuela, segundo que no estoy tratando de insinuar que todos los Chilenos en Venezuela se dediquen a eso, PERO, si ocurrio bastante, quizas no todos eran Chilenos de verdad, puede que enganaran a los locales en eso tambien, pero de que venian de cono sur, venian. Sobretodo sucedio durante los acuerdos del Pacto Andino cuando muchos Surenos tenian acceso a Venezuela sin ningun tipo de revision.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una investigación detallada del tema (centrada en la experiencia Argentina) en el dossier *La invención del cuento del tío*, por Diego Galeano, en el N° 12 de la revista argentina *La Biblioteca*. Lo que digo a continuación tiene esa fuente y me parece convincente.

A la estafa mediante guiones se le ha dado distintos nombres. **Cuento del tío** es el nombre general que se le da en el Cono Sur, con numerosas variantes como *tocomocho, balurdo* o *cambiazo*. **Confidence game** es la versión norteamericana.

Lo curioso: haciendo alusión a algún aspecto de la trama desarrollada en la estafa, en Norteamérica existió el **[spanish prisioner game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Prisoner)**; en Francia el **vol a l'americaine** (robo a la americana); y en Colombia el **paquete chileno**. Y pienso de inmediato en la **[estafa nigeriana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estafa_nigeriana)** (como le decimos en Chile a la estafa por correo electrónico). Vale decir, hay varios casos en los que se relaciona una estafa con un personaje extranjero.

No puedes ser estafador de los que cuentan historias si toda la gente te conoce. Si tienes ese "don" lo más conveniente es que seas itinerante y te vayas con tu historia de pueblo en pueblo. Además es difícil inventar un nuevo guión cada vez, y por lo tanto es preferible seguir usándolo tantas veces como sea posible, para lo cual debes ir moviéndote hacia lugares donde no lo conozcan. Por eso a veces las estafas más efectivas y que causan más impacto y publicidad las perpetran extranjeros. En Chile la estafa más famosa de los últimos tiempos fue la de los *quesitos*, llevada a cabo por una francesa.

Y hay que considerar otros dos asuntos de nuestra idiosincrasia, un poco contradictorios entre sí. (1) A veces sobre todo entre la población con menos cultura, al *gringo* se le atribuyen virtudes morales (serían en algún sentido *superiores* a los locales) que nos vuelven más susceptibles a creerles ([otarios](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RKBBGrk)). Y (2), nuestra natural defensa antropológica ante lo foráneo, causante básica de la xenofobia, nos hace notar más la presencia de los extranjeros en las filas de lo corrupto o ilegal.

Probablemente, como se indica en la respuesta de @sujeto1, en Colombia hubo antaño una estafa en la que estuvieron involucrados un paquete y un chileno. Debe haber sido suficientemente dañina e impactante como para quedar en el léxico colombiano. Y, en resumen, la presencia del extranjero en la historia implica que

- era un estafador itinerante (algo habitual y esperable),
- ser extranjero facilitó la estafa y
- ser extranjero dio mayor notoriedad a la estafa (convirtiéndola en leyenda).

Answer (score 1):

El método de estafa es correcto, pero la historia está incompleta. Se llama así porque cuando los chilenos salieron del país en el 1973 por la dictadura militar, en varios países de Sudamérica, especialmente en Venezuela, los estafaban al comprar sus bienes por precio de huevo.

Pues los chilenos invirtieron la estafa. De esa manera el que se supone los estafaría, salía estafado, porque se supone que compraría joyas, bienes o divisa extranjero, a un precio de miseria aprovechandose de la necesidad de los migrantes, pero los migrantes les vendían basura sin valor, o dinero falso.

Por eso se llama paquete chileno, es una estafa al estafador.

Comment: Qué respuesta tan interesante, Rodrigo, y qué pillos los estafadores de estafadores :) Coincide bastante con lo descrito en las otras respuestas.
 ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Answer (score 0):

El "paquete chileno" no es solo de Colombia, hoy día se usa para cualquier fraude cometido por un chileno, como el del arquero que fingió salir lesionado para interrumpir un partido que estaban perdiendo.

Tengo entendido que se popularizó en el exterior por turistas que al viajar a Chile eran timados por comerciantes de souvenirs: pensaban estar recibiendo algo valioso a cambio de su dinero pero luego se daban cuenta que fueron timados.

La estafa nigeriana por correo electrónico no es como tal. La nigeriana es por correo normal ya que son cheques que envían desde Nigeria en el cual si depositas el cheque y se hace efectivo deberás mandar el 10 o 20 % para que te envíen otro. Lo que sucede es que la ley nigeriana autoriza la transferencia mientras esperan los fondos, así que tu banco te dirá que ya está el dinero y luego Nigeria informa que la cuenta no tenía fondos y te los quitan, pero ya habrás enviado su porcentaje por esos cheques.

Quizás con el tiempo la expresión de *estafa nigeriana* terminará abarcando los de por Internet que te piden una cuenta para sacar su dinero y te ganas un porcentaje y les quitan todo los que tengan en la cuenta y si no tienen saldo en la cuenta la pueden usar para lavado de dólares y por estar a tu nombre sales perjudicado.

Yo diría en el caso de Chile pudo ser la [*malicia indígena*](http://elclavo.com/articulos/opinion/que-es-en-realidad-malicia-indigena/) la que desembocó en esa expresión.

En Venezuela también usamos la expresión de "paquete chileno" y lo he escuchado en series y películas mexicanas así que no creo que Colombia lo inventara.

Comment: La pregunta no es donde se usa sino dónde se originó.

Comment: @Freddy Ordóñez Araque, tu respuesta es discriminatoria, ¿por qué tiene que ser "malicia indígena", son acaso maliciosos los indígenas mientras los mestizos o supuestos blancos, no? Tienes que rectificar tu vocabulario, tus ideas y tu percepción de los demás.

Comment: Otra cosa, vivo hace algún tiempo en Barcelona, España, y es aquí donde por primera vez escuché esa expresión, y además en un noticiero.

Comment: Bueno lo de poner el enlace, aunque se ofrece una explicación sigue siendo discriminatorio el hecho de utilizarla, que por otro lado no define bien lo que quiere decir, no habría sido mejor "picardía", sigo pensando que hay que dejar de usar esa expresión por discriminatoria.

Comment: @AndrésChandía, "malicia indígena"  tal y como se usa en Colombia no es una expresión discriminatoria ya que no se refiere a personas de alguna de las comunidades indígenas que aun existen. Se refiere alguien que usa la astucia con fines poco legales o éticos para sacar provecho propio.

Comment: @alvalongo me estás dando la razón....